# Get min(date), max(date) with group by eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

This query is for getting other data with the highest value of date with the group by/unique. Here I used unique in place of group by.
My question is how to get min(date) and max(date) with group by/unique.
The group by/unique is for Dataset table's date field.
I have searched for this but not getting exact solution that how to get max and min date with group by/unique in laravel eloquent.
In table structure, there are multiple entries for one code so here I used group by/unique to get one record for the code.

There can be multiple dates as 02-01-2003,01-03-2007,01-01-2019, 01-07-2018... etc. with same/ different code. If I group by with code then get onmy one record per code. So here I want to select the max date [01-01-2019] and min date [02-01-2003].

Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
$datasets = Dataset::where('user_id', $user_id)
          ->orderBy('date','desc')
          ->get(['code', 'access','user_id','date'])
          ->unique('code');
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with getting a working query, then move to laravel

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have not created mysql query as Dataset is the collection of mongodb database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution but this can not be the exact solution but as I am beginner and not getting the exact solution I do this functionality as below:

I created two different queries to get min and max values.

```
$min_datasets = Dataset::where('user_id', $user_id)
      ->orderBy('date','asc')
      ->get(['code', 'access','user_id','date'])
      ->unique('code');


$max_$datasets = Dataset::where('user_id', $user_id)
      ->orderBy('date','desc')
      ->get(['code', 'access','user_id','date'])
      ->unique('code');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select max and min date like this:

```
$datasets = Dataset::select('code', 'access','user_id', DB::raw('MAX(date) as max_date'),  DB::raw('MIN(date) as min_date'))
                    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                    ->orderBy('date','desc')
                    ->get()
                    ->unique('code');
```

Comment: I am getting error by this : Illegal offset type in Builder.php line 353

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')->where('user_id',$user_id)
->select('code','access','user_id','date')
->whereBetween('date', [02-01-2003, 01-01-2019])
->groupBy('unique_column')
->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please read my question that I want to get maximum and minimum both the dates. for example there will be minimum date is 02-02-2003 and maximum date is 02-02-2019 in database then I need both the dates. hope you understand my question.

Comment: The exact date or there's a range @Pragna

Comment: I have edited my question with example. Please check

Comment: @Pragna you can use input variable for mindate and maxdate see if my answer fulfill your request or i am still missing out something. Thanks

Comment: In the result of the query there should be maxdate and mindate as in this query of mysql. SELECT MIN(date) AS firstTravelDate, 
       MAX(date) AS LastTravelDate 
FROM travel_data 
GROUP BY `from`, to;

Comment: I have added a mindate and maxdate for searching purpose. Am i on the correct path as you're mentioning?

Comment: No. no need for searching. I want it in result only. no need to compare it.

Comment: You can hardcode the value for mindate and maxdate, i am doing this query for your reference purpose as i have limited info from your over system. Hope you make adjustment and try it out. Looking forward for your results if you can retrieve and show

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer (not to the comment section) such that the OP can learn from your answer

Comment: @Pragna i have made adjustment please adjust the variable and dd($data);